# Function working fine in stand alone mode but not in a larger program

Tags: c, function, segmentation-fault

I have a c program with multiple headers and source files. On running, the program gives segmentation fault. On using "up" and "print variable" commands, i figured that the function "busntoint()" is not working properly.

I have following functions for converting a string of length n from binary to decimal:

```
unsigned int busntoint(int n, busn bus)
{
    unsigned int value = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
            if (bus[i] == '1') value += (unsigned int)pow(2,(n-1-i));
    }
    return value;
}
unsigned int bus2toint(bus2 bus) 
{
    return busntoint(2, bus);
}
unsigned int bus32toint(bus32 bus) 
{
    return busntoint(32, bus);
}
```

I then wrote another program to check the working of these functions. It works just fine and gives the correct and expected output. I dunno why it is not working properly in the "bigger" program.

If it's useful, following is the definition of variables:

```
typedef char bus2[3];
typedef char bus3[4];
typedef char bus5[6];
typedef char bus6[7];
typedef char bus8[9];
typedef char bus16[17];
typedef char bus32[33];
```

The usage of the function in the "bigger" program is as follows:

```
int LoadMemory(char * binfilename, bus8 memory[4096])
{
    //some code
    int addr = bus32toint(line);
    setbit8(memory[addr], &line[33]);
    //some code
}
```

p addr in gdb gives garbage value, leading to segmentation fault in memory[addr].

Comment: What are `busn`, `bus2`, and `bus32`?

Comment: @CarlNorum : I have updated the question with the declaration of busn

Comment: These functions look fine, but maybe some other code is calling busntoint() with a value of n that doesn't match the buffer size.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill : I'm sorry but i did not get you clearly. And if so, how do i check it?

Comment: And what do the calls in the bigger program look like?

Comment: @ott-- : i have updated the question, giving the details of the call.

Comment: `addr` is an index, not a memory address. But your function doesn't return an index.

Comment: @ott-- : it returns an "unsigned int" value, which can be used as an index

Comment: Save yourself the pain of poring over your code and bUild it with debugging on and then run it through Valgrind.

Comment: Are you sure your line buffer is not containing a wrong value, that will give an addr higher or equal to 4096 ?

Comment: @StephaneD. : i checked "line". its value is less that 4096

Comment: @JamesMorris : Could you give a useful link on how to do that?

Comment: Just google 'how to use valgrind'.

Comment: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem probably lies in your abuse of `pow` to compute powers of two and the possible overflow that your computation may encounter.

The correct way of computing integer powers of two is the shift operator, here that would be

```
2u << (n-1-i)
```

the suffix `u` is to ensure that this has the correct type (`unsigned`). But then you also have to ensure that the value by which you are shifting is not too large, you must guarantee that the corresponding power will still fit into an `unsigned`. You didn't tell us on what architecture your are, not all have `unsigned` with 32 bit.

Then your `LoadMemory` function also looks bogus. As far as I can see there can no guarantee be given that `addr` (for which you didn't show the type) is smaller than `4096`.

Comment: @nish, you return an `unsigned` and store it in an `int`? don't do that keep your types clear.

Comment: i changed the type of addr. Also I checked the "line" variable. Its value id less than 4096. "line" is a string of length 32.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unsigned int addr =  bus32toint(line);`